# Securing content url using TEA algo

Tags: java, algorithm, security

We are creating one node app .. we want to get the front client to call java based REST api to deliver the content in encrypted form , and the client should be able to decrypt the content and get the video url to play on the JW player.

Someone suggested the TEA algo for this , where we encrypt the content from java and decrypt the content at JW player end to get the video urls.

Is there any alternative to TEA algo , as if i encrypt it using java it is not getting decrypted properly.

Comment: Just use HTTPS/TLS, the data will be encrypted in transit and you will not have a key to share with the client.

Comment: The current "go to" encryption algorythm is AES, the name says it all: Advanced Encryption Standard. That said TEA is not nearly as secure as AES, at least use XTEA or XXTEA.